# Rails console won't load environment variables in secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

I am trying to debug a problem with `secrets.yml` loading environment variables, by setting some environment variables in development and running `rails c` to inspect things.  When I load `Rails.applications.secrets` this way, it is not picking up any of the environment variables I have set (namely, `SECRET_KEY_BASE`)

If I run the application with the same environment variables set, it picks them up fine (I'm using RubyMine to run the application, but running `rails c` from the terminal)

In my rails console, I can see the environment variable I've set using `ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']`, but it doesn't show up in `Rails.application.secrets`.  Why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `spring stop`

It turns out, as has happened so many times when things aren't making any sense, Spring is the culprit!  I solved this problem (thanks to [a related discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19256)) by running `spring stop` and then trying again, after which it worked perfectly!

Apparently Spring was caching the environment, or certain pieces of the Rails application, and neglecting to reload them when the environment variables changed.

Comment: See this issue in the Spring repository: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/490

Comment: Yeah Spring is annoying. This is why I start my rails applications with --skip-spring every time.

Comment: Interesting, direnv (https://github.com/direnv/direnv) was not working properly because of that, and now it works! Thank you

Comment: or `bin/spring stop` for n00bz like me.

Comment: Hi, Joe! You just saved me some frustration. Hope all is well!

Comment: Haha, hey Brad!  Happy to help ;D